# Login to website with multiple client certificates

Tags: certificate, internet-explorer

I have users that need to access a website with a different client certificate depending on what function they are trying to perform.

The problem is that once the user logs in with one of the client certificates, the only way they can log in with a different certificate is to close every instance of Internet Explorer that is open first.

Is there any way to force Internet Explorer to try to log in with a different certificate?

I have tried having the users click the "Clear SSL state" button under Internet Options > Content, but that seems to only work about 25% of the time.

Answer (score 0):

why dont you get a SAN certificate, that would work across multiple domains..by using a single certificate..

Comment: We have no control over the certificates or the website. The website generates the certificates and we can only use the certificates that they generate. They give us one certificate per role but we have users that fill multiple rolls, which means they have to use more than one certificate.